# Search core data for closest value

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

Currently we have a database of multiple values for r,g,b, split into own attributes. ex:

```
 r = type float
 g = type float
 b = type float
```

There will be multiple values for each r, g, and b attribute.
 After getting a float from an outside source, we want to search the database to return the attribute with the closest number to that float. (ex. for r, if we get a value of 199, the r value with the closest value to 199 will be returned).

I know there are predicates that can be used like: `"text CONTAINS[c] %@"` but I didn't see any predicates for 'closest value'.

Comment: You have to define some range of your term `closest`. For me closest of 199 can be 220 but for someone else it is not closest. Do you have any threshold value for this?

Comment: @UmairAamir there isn't a threshold value, it just needs to grab the closest value.  The database contains thousands of values for, r, g, b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSSortDescriptor(key: "name_key", ascending: true)` with your request.

```
let request1 = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>() // use correct constructor
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name_key", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
request1.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "text < %@", value)
request1.predicate = predicate1
// use this request1 to fetch from core data

let request2 = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>() // use correct constructor
request2.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "text > %@", value)
request2.predicate = predicate2
// use this requst2 to fetch from core data
```

Then you can use `predicate` twice:

First time with format `text < %@` and use last item of the array.

*and*

Second time with format `text > %@` and use the first item of the array.

compare the difference of your first and last items from both iterations with your given value and see whose difference is smaller. That will be closest value.

If you don't know how to fetch data from core data you can follow [Fetching Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html)

[Getting started with core data](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173972/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial-2)

Comment: Can you use predicate to search through sort descriptors?

Comment: "search through sort descriptors"?
Basically `predicates` and `sort descriptors` are incorporated with `fetch requests`. Not sure how you are trying to do.

Comment: I dont think i'm completely clear on your answer, how would you use predicate twice?

Comment: Ok, so to find the closest number at the end : if request1 > request2 { r = request1}

Comment: What is `name_key` and what does it have to do with the numeric RGB values mentioned in the question?

Comment: It is attribute name. On its basis you’ll sort your data. For example if you want to sort on the basis of `r` then you’ll pass `r` instead of `name_key`